# Drag and drop functionality using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

I want to implement the functionality something like Example 1.3 given on [this website](http://devheart.org/examples/jquery-customizable-layout-using-drag-and-drop/1-getting-started-with-sortable-lists/index.html). Please help with that.

Comment: Have you worked on it?

Comment: downlaod example code from that website http://devheart.org/articles/jquery-customizable-layout-using-drag-and-drop/

Comment: tutorial http://devheart.org/articles/jquery-customizable-layout-using-drag-and-drop/

Comment: Yes..You need to try implementing first!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s1jd9d4k/) using the demo page

for html

```
<div id="example-1-3">
            <div class="column left first">
                <ul class="sortable-list">
                    <li class="sortable-item">Sortable item A</li>
                    <li class="sortable-item">Sortable item B</li>
                </ul>

            </div>

            <div class="column left">

                <ul class="sortable-list">
                    <li class="sortable-item">Sortable item C</li>
                    <li class="sortable-item">Sortable item D</li>
                </ul>

            </div>

            <div class="column left">

                <ul class="sortable-list">
                    <li class="sortable-item">Sortable item E</li>
                </ul>

            </div>

            <div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>

        </div>
```

for  js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Example 1.3: Sortable and connectable lists with visual helper
$('#example-1-3 .sortable-list').sortable({
    connectWith: '#example-1-3 .sortable-list',
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code on the page you've mentioned:

```
    // Example 1.3: Sortable and connectable lists with visual helper
    $('#example-1-3 .sortable-list').sortable({
        connectWith: '#example-1-3 .sortable-list',
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
    });
```

Just set the `connectWith` to an #id or .class and that's it.
The HTML (as seen in the demo on the link) for it would be:

```
            <div id="example-1-3">

                <div class="column left first">

                    <ul class="sortable-list">
                        <li class="sortable-item">Sortable item A</li>
                        <li class="sortable-item">Sortable item B</li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

                <div class="column left">

                    <ul class="sortable-list">
                        <li class="sortable-item">Sortable item C</li>
                        <li class="sortable-item">Sortable item D</li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

                <div class="column left">

                    <ul class="sortable-list">
                        <li class="sortable-item">Sortable item E</li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

                <div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with the below link if it works with you.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jU8Pp/135/)

```
$(".DragItem").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: "clone"
});

$(".drop1").droppable({
     accept: '.drag1',
     activeClass: 'DropTargetValid',
     drop: function (ev, ui) {
        $(ev.target).append(ui.draggable.clone());
      }
});

$(".drop2").droppable({
    accept: '.drag2',
    activeClass: 'DropTargetValid',
    drop: function (ev, ui) {
        $(ev.target).append(ui.draggable.clone());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
        $('html').niceScroll({cursorcolor:"#639BF6",cursorwidth :10, cursorborder: 'none'});
        //dad simple demo
        $('.dad').dad();
    })
```

```html
<script src="http://konsolestudio.com/dad/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://konsolestudio.com/source/jquery.dad.js"></script>
<script src="http://konsolestudio.com/dad/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://konsolestudio.com/source/jquery.dad.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://konsolestudio.com/dad/demo.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div id="daddy" class="dad">
        <div>
            <div>1</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>2</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>3</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>4</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>5</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>6</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>7</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>8</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>10</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hi aman try this: